# How to share enums between database and application?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

How can I share enumerations between a website application and the database? For example, if I have a `TYPE` table like this:

id | name

1  type1

2 type2

and an enum:

```js
enum Type {
    type1 = 1,
    type2 = 2
}
```

is there a way to automatically link both, for example when the database is empty, the application should add those two rows so the enum used in the application matches the type used in the DB. I want to do that because in the DB, a `product` might be of type `furniture` (so the `type_id` of the `product` references the type `furniture` in the table `TYPE`) but I also want to be able to do something like

```js
if (type === Type.furniture) {
    // ...
}
```

directly from the application logic (for example to change the front end depending on the type).
This is a pretty common problem so how would you manage it? Is there another way than manually ensuring that both matches?

Comment: Is this php?? Or javascript? Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an ORM of some kind? If yes, is it Code-first approach or database-first approach?

I know you can do something like that by using C# + EFcore. You have to use the HasData() method of the ModelBuilder. The workflow to achieve your goal would be: Get all members of your enumeration and populate your db table with them. If you are not using EFcore and C#, I guess you can follow a similar approach to your problem by finding the appropriate seeding method of your ORM and the appropriate way to extract all members of your enumeration.
For the second part of your problem, you will need to directly edit the file which stores your enumeration.